# layer.find won't return a kineticjs object by id although it exists

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have the following issue: I create two different customObjects I created, that include some kineticjs objects. On each of them I have some Kinetijs Lines. The id's of the lines are different inside the custom object but could be the between the two different mycustom objects. Meaning

```
 mycustomobj1 hass lines with id1, id2, id3, id4
 mycustomobj2 has also lines with id1, id2, id3, id4
```

Each line is placed inside a group and and group on a layer lets say lineGroup and basicLayer
and a lineGroup has many lines in it

I do the following on mycustomobj1

```
mycustomobj1.lineGroup.getChildren()
```

and returns me all the lines placed inside this group. And one of them is line with id1. But when I do

```
mycstomobj1.basicLayer.find("#id1");
```

i get an empty array.

What can be wrong?

and example code. I have extracted line from my obect (the lineGroup)

```
lines.getChildren()[11]
Kinetic.Line 
    {nodeType: "Shape", 
    _fillFunc: function, 
    _strokeFunc: function, 
    _fillFuncHit: function, 
    _strokeFuncHit: function…}
    _cache: Object
    _fillFunc: function a(a){a.fill()}
    _fillFuncHit: function c(a){a.fill()}
    _filterUpToDate: 
    false_id: 47
    _strokeFunc: function b(a){a.stroke()}
    _strokeFuncHit: function d(a){a.stroke()}
    attrs: Object
        id: "red0"
        points: Array[48]
        sceneFunc: function (a){var b,c,d,e=this.getPoints(),f=e.length,g=this.getTension(),h=this.getClosed();if(a.beginPath(),a.moveTo(e[0],e[1]),0!==g&&f>4){for(b=this.getTensionPoints(),c=b.length,d=h?0:4,h||a.quadraticCurveTo(b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);c-2>d;)a.bezierCurveTo(b[d++],b[d++],b[d++],b[d++],b[d++],b[d++]);h||a.quadraticCurveTo(b[c-2],b[c-1],e[f-2],e[f-1])}else for(d=2;f>d;d+=2)a.lineTo(e[d],e[d+1]);h?(a.closePath(),a.fillStrokeShape(this)):a.strokeShape(this)}stroke: "red"strokeWidth: 2
    __proto__: Object
    className:"Line"
    colorKey: "#372306"
    eventListeners: Object
    index: 11
    nodeType: "Shape"
    parent: Kinetic.Group__proto__: Object

lines.find("#red0")
[]
```

EDIT: It worked after changing the ids to be unique between them and between the objects but I don't think this is the correct behavour.

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't think so because it involes too much. 8 different tables, the custom object creation the testing. I can post the Line creation code for each object if you think it will help

Answer (score 1):

Each `id` of `Node` MUST be unique. Try to use deffirent `id`. This is by KineticJS design. If you need not unique values you may use `name` property.

Comment: Yes but i have two diferent stage and kineticjs objects...but on the same dom. Maybe that's the problem right?